# librosa module import in python3 throws warning

Tags: python

i have installed module librosa in python3 using the command but when i am trying to import this module it shows below warning

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py", line 9
    from numba.decorators import jit as optional_jit
NumbaDeprecationWarning: An import was requested from a module that has moved location.
Import requested from: 'numba.decorators', please update to use 'numba.core.decorators' or pin to Numba version 0.48.0. This alias will not be present in Numba version 0.50.0.
```

Comment: You should literally do what the warning suggests

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
pip3 install numba==0.48.0
```

Comment: Users may want to consider whether or not they want to pin to this version of numba in the long-run. Ideally librosa should update to use 'numba.core.decorators'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. in the cmd of your windows write this:
   pip install librosa soundfile numpy sklearn pyaudio

PS:
if you have for example "numpy and sklearn" already installed please write this:
pip install librosa soundfile pyaudio (install what you do not have)

than in the same CMD follow this:

2. pip uninstall scikit-learn
3. pip install scikit-learn==0.19.1
4. pip install numba==0.48.0